# How to change Domain database connection of Informatica server after instalation

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

The informatica server is configured on linux based system .
Now the domain database connection got changed. I mean the port number was changed due to some issue. 
Now the infa services fails to start up . Please let me know how to change the configuration now.

Comment: which version of Informatica are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the infasetup.sh command to update connectivity information for domain configuration database.

Switch to the directory `<InformaticaInstallationDir>/isp/bin`. Then run the below command with database details

`infasetup.sh UpdateGatewayNode -da  database_hostname:database_port -du database_user_name -dp database_password -dt oracle -ds database_service_name -dn domain_name`

OR

`infasetup.sh UpdateGatewayNode -ds "jdbc:informatica:oracle://host_name:port;SID=sid" -du database_user_name -dp database_password -dt oracle -dn domain_name`